# Making queries from existing tables (postgresql) in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have already created a set of tables with Postgresql,  I would like, to make a query directly from tables to Django views without writing any models to pose as a form?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) management command to automatically generate models from an existing database:

`python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

For more information, see the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Thank you, and apologize as can't up-vote due to my low reputations.

Comment: Hello J.McBride, this will only creating the models out of tables where they came with django!  is there anyway to point to desired  - created database or  Schema?

Comment: Thank you I found answer for my problem!                                   https://www.amvtek.com/blog/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/